# Something like firebase.database.TIMESTAMP for firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Is there something equivalent to [firebase.database.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP) for Firebase Firestore ?

I would like that the timestamp of a field be determined by the Firebase servers in a write operation.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46855006/4815718

Comment: @BobSnyder The FieldValue.serverTimestamp() only exists in firebase-admin (according to Frank van Pufflen answer), that requires server. I am using Web SDK, that runs in Browsers. Is there any way to use it in Firebase JS ?

Comment: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` available in all client SDKs, [including Javascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue).

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks. It worked.

Comment: This question is _not_ a duplicate of [How do I get the server timestamp _in Cloud Functions_ for Firebase with Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46647964/2054731). This question is about how to solve it in javascript (like in a Web application), which the other question does not ask about, nor has it received any answers telling us how to do it. This question should be reopened, so a "right answer" similar to @BobSnyder's 2nd comment, above, can be posted.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

You are fetching the timestamp from firebase db irrespective of which database you use either firestore or realtime database.

Comment: When I tried using `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in Firestore, I just got an object like this: `{ sv: "timestamp"}`, so unless I made some other mistake it is not usable in Firestore.

Comment: Instead, use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. It is the equivalend for Firestore.