# Adding Server Timestamp field to the Object which being added

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Challenge` object, which has it's own properties and I'm able to add it to the database successfully like this:

```
DocumentReference challengeRef=usersRef.document(loggedUserEmail).collection("challenges_feed").
                document(callengeID);
challengeRef.set(currentChallenge);
```

This is how it looks like in the database:

[image]

I'd like to make a new field in the database (under this challenge) which called `latestUpdateTimetamp`. This is how it *should* look like (I have added it manually):

[image]

I have tried to set it in the `constructor` of the `object` like this:

```
private Map<String,String> latestUpdateTimestamp;

public Challenge(String id, String senderName,  String senderEmail) {   
            this.senderName=senderName;
            this.senderEmail = senderEmail;

            this.latestUpdateTimestamp= ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        }
```

But this is what I get in the `database`:

[image]

**I'm trying to add the `latestUpdateTimestamp` to the `Challenge` and the `Challenge` object itself to the database at the same call. Is it possible?**

Can I somehow add this `timestamp` as a property to this `object` before adding it?

I know I'm able to make a new call and add this field, but I'm wondering if it's possible at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set epoch in Firestore using server time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851220/how-to-set-epoch-in-firestore-using-server-time)

Comment: ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a Realtime Database value.  Firestore does it differently.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes you can, using a `Map`. First of all, according to [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp) it will be necessary to use an annotation that looks like this:

```
@ServerTimestamp Date time;
```

> Annotation used to mark a Date field to be populated with a server timestamp. If a POJO being written contains null for a @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced with a server-generated timestamp.

This is how you can update the `latestUpdateTimestamp` field with the server timestamp and the `challangeId` with the desired value at the same time.

```
DocumentReference senderRef = challengeRef
    .document(loggedUserEmail)
    .collection("challenges_feed")
    .document(callengeID);

Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("latestUpdateTimestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
updates.put("challengeId", "newChallangeId");
senderRef.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {/* ... */}
```

Comment: @AlexMamo is the field annotated with `@ServerTimestamp` stored in Firestore as a unix timestamp (e.g. "1535876245") or as a full datetime (e.g. "2018-09-02T08:17:25+00:00")?

Comment: @Clyky None of those, is stored using the `Date` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo what if I want to implement it in an already running Firebase project where earlier, I had a field `createdAt: String` that contains unix Timestamp and now to sync the data for all the Timezones I prefer to use the `ServerTimestamp`. So, how can I update this while being able to use the previous Data?

Comment: @VikashSharma It's a bit complex to respond in a comment. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry to post here, but I am unable to post a separate question due to my previous questions that do not follow the MCVE. So, it would be helpful if you could help me with this query here.

Answer (score 4):

As per Google Documentation You can use **FieldValue.serverTimestamp()**. Something like this

Java

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id");
Map<String,Object> post = new HashMap<>();
post.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

docRef.add(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
 .....
}
```

Kotlin

```
val docRef = db.collection("objects").document("some-id")
val updates = HashMap<String, Any>()
updates["timestamp"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

docRef.add(updates).addOnCompleteListener { }
```

Answer (score 3):

### Kotlin

In kotlin we need to define an initialized data class to send the whole object to Firestore, make sure that you add your `@ServerTimeStamp` in the last field, since if you add it at first, the construction of your object will need to pass this time as a value to your Object instance.

```
data class Order(val orderId:String, val cart:MutableList<Cart>, @ServerTimeStamp timestamp:Date? = null)
```

Create your object and send the object values to Firestore

```
val order = Order("kJKLkj259ajHHkl",cartList)

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("orders").add(order)...
```

This will create your object with orderId, cartlist and also the timestamp which will be stored as

[image]

In my case I'm from Argentina, and the date picked up from my app was this one

```
timestamp: 30 de marzo de 2020, 10:12:43 UTC-3
```

You can find more about date formats [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/Date_Format_Types.html)

Answer (score 1):

So you could use Firebase tools to do so.

Basically if you use @ServerTimestamp in your object and pass nil as a value then the server will automatically add a server timestamp.

Not sure how to do it in Java as I am a Swift developer, but just to give you an example this is what I added in my object model:

```
//This is a Swift code for demonstration
@ServerTimestamp var timeStamp: Timestamp?
```

So here it just says there is a variable named timeStamp of an optional Timestamp data type and there is no value assigned so it is nil.

And then I upload the object as I would do normally without passing any value with timeStamp.

This means it is uploaded as nil and Firestore automatically assigns it a server timestamp.