# Firebase firestore subcollection ordering and limit

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a subcollection with the path of `/coll_A/document_A/coll_B`, where coll_A/_B - are collections. I want to query this subcollection with ordering and limit:

```
firestore.collection("coll_A")
        .document("document_A")
        .collection("coll_B")
        .orderBy("time", DESCENDING)
        .limit(10)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(...)
```

But it always returns the full collection. What am I doing wrong?

`time` is a number timestamp.

**Upd**.: `time` is just an example, I used an integer field before. As per answer from Alex Mamo, it should be able to order by it.

**Upd. 2** I tried to prepare a screenshot and removed and re-added the data - and it started to work. Data is all the same, collection-doc-collection hierarchy also, so probably some kind of a glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, your date should be stored as a `Date` object as explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474957/servertimestamp-is-allways-null-on-firebase-firestore/48475027)** and not as a number as you say. So to solve this, please change your query to:

```
firestore.collection("coll_A")
    .document("document_A")
    .collection("coll_B")
    .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(...)
```

As per [Firestore Supported Data Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) documentation, you can sort your records **`chronological`** by date and time. Saving the date and time as a **[ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)** was useful when using Firebase Realtime database. In the new Cloud Firestore, you need to store the date as a `Date` object in order to be able to sort your records according to it. Please see also here informations about [ServerTimestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp):

> Annotation used to mark a timestamp field to be populated with a server timestamp. If a POJO being written contains null for a @ServerTimestamp-annotated field, it will be replaced with a server-generated timestamp.

So this is the correct way in which you can achieve what you want.

If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355540/firestore-adding-server-timestamp-field-to-the-object-which-being-added)** is how you can update a Date in case you need it.

**Edit:**

You can order by integers or strings but keep in mind this: When ordering by strings remember that [strings are ordered lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key) while ordering by `date` you'll get a `chronological order`.

The object that results from setting a Cloud Firestore field with [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#serverTimestamp()) is an instance of [java.util.Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html). When you later read the value, you can get the epoch time using [getTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()). This is why Firebase team added this new supported data type, which is more useful then the regular data stored as a number.

If you want to improve your query with more limitation you can use also `whereEqualTo()`, `whereGreaterThan()`, `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo()`, `whereLessThan()` or `whereLessThanOrEqualTo()`.

As a conclusion, the best way to store a date is to store it a `Date` object.

Comment: But I don't want a date, it should be orderable and limitable by a number

Comment: I still don't follow - I can't order and limit by an integer, string, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the update, the problem is it doesn't work. I know and expect the lexicographically sorting of strings, and I expect the ints to be sorted out of the box. The time in the post is also just a number, it should be sortable/limittable

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database structure. Is there any other limitation that you are using in your query other than `orderBy` and `limit`?

Comment: please see my update - it suddenly started working, I think I should accept your answer as gives good answer on how the ordering should be.