# Am I structuring this firestore query correctly?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get all documents within the specified date/time range (all within the same day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59)

Ive tried multiple querys, and there is nothing in the docs about querying the same date with different times.
Most examples show a specific date/time, but I need the query to be all documents scheduled for today(dynamic)

```
private void loadList() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date todayStart = c.getTime();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    Date todayEnd = c.getTime();
    Log.d(TAG, "this is the date/time for todayStart" + todayStart);
    Log.d(TAG, "this is the date/time for todayEnd" + todayEnd);

    mFirestoreDB.collection("events")
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("dateScheduled", todayStart)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("dateScheduled", todayEnd)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {... ect
```

Example Firestore field:
dateScheduled
May 5, 2019 at 12:00:00 AM UTC-4

Example 2:

[image]

The Log.d is showing correct date/times for today, and I have many documents that have the todays date scheduled.
This should return all documents with any time frame for todays date.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show an example of a document that you expect to match.  Please be specific about its contents - fields and data types. Without seeing exactly what you expect to match, it's not possible for us to predict if it's going to match.

Comment: I thought the example under the code snippet was what you would like to see, but I added a picture.

Comment: It wasn't 100% clear if you are working with a Timestamp type field, or just a formatted string.

Comment: check out this. Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("latestUpdateTimestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp()); - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355540/firestore-adding-server-timestamp-field-to-the-object-which-being-added